# Data of those applications which are uninstalled previously (from beginning)

Tags: android, devise, android-download-manager, android-hardware

I am working on an application where im getting all the applications which are currently and previously installed in the device..

My application is showing all the applications which are currently installed in the device now i want the information of those applications which were previously installed and uninstalled.

Please help me out with this issue.. I heard there is some file in the devise which stores all the information of the applications.

Thankyou.